Do we always use "worsen" with something which is already bad?
The simple definition of worsen is to become or make something worse. However, in all the examples that I have seen, I noticed that the things being worsened had already been bad in the first place. For example:

The problem has worsened considerably in recent months.
Her symptoms have worsened considerably since we last saw her.
The study also said road congestion is expected to worsen in that area in the next 20 years.

So, can we use worsen with something good, e.g., worsen his happy life?

Yes, worse and its derivative worsen imply that something was not very good to start with. (When I was a child, not used to the way fashions change, I was shown a photo of my mother taken 20 years earlier (she was 39 when I was born) and said thoughtfully "You looked worse then than you do now". Of course I didn't mean "You look unattractive now", just that I would have expected her to look more attractive when she was younger, and to my eyes the 1930s fashions in hair and spectacles were simply odd. She was amused rather than offended!)

Thanks. So, what can I use when that thing is not necessarily bad at first? detract from?

It would depend on the context. For your 'happy life' example, perhaps 'bring his happy life in [place] to an end', 'change his life for ever' (the context would show what you meant 'change for the worse'), 'bring trouble into his life', for example.

Simple answer: you can only worsen something that is already not good. Usually a situation.

There is no semantic difference between "my sister is younger than my brother" and "my brother is older than my sister". Nor is there a semantic difference between "the situation three months ago was better than the situation now" and "the situation now is worse than the situation three months ago". Nevertheless, language is not applied pure logic. So, "the situation has worsened over the last three months" would only be used if the change is from bad to very bad, not if it is from very good to just good etc. -- For the other direction of change, "the situation has improved" might always work

No, you can't use it that way - 'worse' is a comparative adjective, so to say one thing is "worse" than another means both are bad to some degree. When you compare things, you're comparing on a particular metric; in this case, how 'bad' two things are. Generally speaking, the two things being compared have to share that quality - for example, it would be weird to ask "which is hotter - the Arctic or the Antarctic?". You'd more likely ask which is colder because, on average, they are both differing degrees of cold.
Your suggestion of "worsen his happy life" therefore doesn't make sense. A happy life isn't bad, so it can't 'worsen'.
Say instead something like it "impacts" or "affects" his life. If it completely takes away all the happiness, you might go as far as to say it "spoiled" or "ruined" his happy life.

Thank you. But I thought impact and affect deliver a neutral meaning? Sometimes A can affect B positively, can't it? Does detract from work?

Neutral, yes, but the context will often answer that question. The bus drivers' strike impacted his travel arrangements implies that his travel situation is bad now, whether it was good or bad before.

It's not true at all that comparative adjectives require both things to have that quality in isolation. That's why it's a comparison. A six-month-old is older than a newborn, Venus is cooler than the sun, I'm better at the theremin than I was a month ago.

You might not ask which of the Arctic or Antarctic is hotter, but you'd certainly ask which is warmer

@NoName Honestly, I don't think many would ask that. It might be grammatically sound and on a purely scientific level you can refer to an increase in temperature as 'warmth' - but in every day speech you'd have people smirking at you, unless they consider 5°C to be 'warm'.

@the-baby-is-you Sure, there are seeming exceptions, but your examples are flawed. "Older" isn't a comparison of "old", is it? "Old" isn't a quality that anyone possesses. It is a comparison of age, and even a newborn baby has 'age'. Your other examples are contextual and quite convoluted - Venus is not a star and does not produce its own heat. Like all the planets in our solar system, it gets its heat and light from the sun. So the comparison is really the sun's own heat on its surface compared to its heat 67 million miles away.

@Astralbee If a newborn has age, Antarctica has heat. All of them are gradable properties, that's the point. I don't think my examples are exceptional or convoluted at all, and the heat source thing is completely irrelevant. I'll grant that we tend to use the weakest adjective available ("warm" instead of "hot") and in some cases talk about it in that jokey well technically way ("I mean, it's warmer than Antarctica!"), but none of that makes it incorrect as a rule.

@the-baby-is-you Again, I feel you've missed the point. If you're one of the 4% of western university students that study physics then yes, you view heat as the transfer of thermal energy between systems or objects, but everybody else would probably default to the primary dictionary definition which is "the quality of being hot; high temperature". My point is that neither poles are considered to be "hot" or have "high temperatures", relatively speaking.

I think the main claim of this answer — that comparative adjectives and their associated verbs are only used with things that share the base quality in isolation — is typically true, but not quite as absolute as this answer suggest.  @the-baby-is-you’s original counterexample sounds completely natural to me; for another example, imagine consoling a child who came second in a competition: “It’s OK — sure, you did worse than Alice, but you still did very well!”

@PLL you say it is "typically true". My answer says "generally speaking". Nowhere do I say that the two things must share that base quality "in isolation", and I wouldn't say that because it is nonsense. Some things may share multiple comparable metrics yet still not be identical. I'd ask you to read my answer again.

I won’t use worsen to describe a good situation becoming not as good.  The adjectives bad and worse are closely related as seen from phrases like from bad to worse. Thus worsen has the inalienable sense of bad.
We may need to use more words like become not as good (or great) or drop in standard.
Something has caused his happy life to become not as great.
Edit
We could also consider dilute as in the usage dilute a good something, dilute a happy ending as in The Songs of the Kings: A Novel, dilute a good case, dilute a good deal, and dilute a good concept.
Edit
Also possible are mar and blemish, from M+W and Collins Dictionary respectively:

to ruin or diminish the perfection or wholeness of


He wasn't about to blemish that pristine record.

Something has diluted (marred, or blemished) his happy life.

So there's no word that simply means "make something not as good as before"?

Some incident slightly marred his otherwise happy life
or A minor blemish on an otherwise good show
--Possible suggestions

Thanks, @Weiwen Ng, for the good suggestions.  I have added them to my answer but with the verb form of blemish.

"Degrade" was my first thought.

Thanks, @Dave X.  Degrade is general enough and should be possible.  I found some usages of degrade(d) his life in Google Books.

In a comment the OP asks  "So there's no word that simply means 'make something not as good as before'?"
There are specific verbs for specific types of harm (e.g. cracked, scratched, snapped, crushed) but for an unspecified harm ("made it not as good as before") we can use the verb mar figuratively:

it marred their good relationship
The newspaper article was marred by several  misquotes.

The literal meaning of the verb mar is to damage a thing in a way that doesn't affect its functionality, like a scratch on a piece of furniture, and the figurative meaning is to damage something in an intangible manner that causes it to be less good (in some way -- less attractive, less perfect, less authentic, and so on).  The verb damage would also work sometimes. It would work with the relationship example above but not with the newspaper article example.
Or we can resort to the tired and wordy:

it had a negative effect on their good relationship

